# Limit git clone access to a specific repo on GitHub

Tags: git, github

I want to be able to perform on a remote machine a git clone operation of a specific repo.

However I was unable to find a way to apply such restriction with ssh keys, let alone I would not want to add my ssh key in another machine.

Is there a mechanism that will allow

a) only git read action (git clone specifically)

b) limited to one and only one repo?

(or at least, regarding b, make this configurable i.e. fine tune the repos that can be accessed)

Comment: I think you are looking for [deploy keys](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/managing-deploy-keys#deploy-keys)

Comment: this seems the way to go; if you post this as an answer I will mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [deploy keys](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/managing-deploy-keys#deploy-keys):

> [a deploy key] an SSH key that grants access to a single repository. GitHub attaches the public part of the key directly to your repository instead of a personal user account, and the private part of the key remains on your server.